# How to run Executor Service on a list and perform some action in Java

Tags: java, executorservice

I have a list of items which I want to run an executor service to perform some expensive action:

```
var myList = Arrays.asList("item1", "item2");
var es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

myList.foreach(item -> {
    es.submit(() -> {
        performExpensiveAction(item);
    })
})

es.shutdown();
```

Say I have 100 items in the list, I expect the es to performExpensiveAction on all 100 items but it only performs the action on 10 items.

Comment: Add a call to `awaitTermination` after the `shutdown` call.  The shutdown only *initiates* the shutdown.  It doesn't wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using **invokeAll** instead **shutdown**.

> The **shutdown()** method will allow previously submitted tasks to execute before terminating,

> while the **shutdownNow()** method prevents waiting tasks from starting and attempts to stop currently executing tasks.

> Methods **invokeAny** and **invokeAll** perform the most commonly useful forms of bulk execution, executing a collection of tasks and then waiting for at least one, or all, to complete. (invokeAll waiting for all)

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)